# Linkinfo is not getting generated properly in few targets

Tags: publishing, 2011-sp1, publishtransaction, link-info, link-resolver

I have a strange behavior in my application.

I am using file system at the content delivery side. I can see that all linkinfo is created as csv files.

This linkinfo is not getting created properly on some of the targets. This is storing information about anchor tags.

It is working fine with the same code and same configurations in another machine. I have observerd the Transaction zip files, logs. I cannot see any information in logs.

**Update 1**
This will be created like this in general.

```
52277,-1,200,0,/abcd/home/index.html#section-2
pageid, -1, 200, 0, path-to-anchortag
```

but now its gettign created as

```
52277,27551,200,0,/abcd/home/index.html
pageid, comptempid, 200,0, pagepathwithoutanchortag
```

Any ideas to start debugging this.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "not getting created properly"? How is it created, why do you think it isn't correct, etc. What are the symptoms caused by this?

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov. I have edited the question added the information required. Basically it has information about all component links. We have custom deployer developed. There is no code changes at cms side and cd side for a long time. can you guide us

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the details of the format that Tridion stores component link info on the file system, but if the configurations are the same on both, the working machine and the broken one, and yet the outputs formats are different, it could be an issue with the lib versions. Is it possible one of the machines is running an older version of some Tridion jars?

Answer (score 2):

I distinctly remember seeing this question before and the answer was that you would have to debug your custom deployer as this information is NOT stored by the regular Tridion deployer!

I would first check to ensure that you are not overwriting the output of your custom deployer with output generated by a standard Tridion deployer (either due to configuration issues or by having >1 deployer running).

Comment: Thank you for the clue. Yes I can see that the output of custom deployer is being overridden. I have kept the breakpoints in my custom deployer but later I see that it is getting overridden. Can you tell what could be possible options for this.

Comment: Make sure there's only one deployer first; then post the cd_deployer_conf.xml contents here so we can have a look